# How do I make sure an int is only deducted once in a while loop (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have created a program 'bulls and cows'. In it, the computer randomly generates a four-digit number. The user then has to guess a four-digit number. If the number is in the computers 4 digit number then you get a bull, if it is not you get a cow. The program runs until the user gets all four digits.

I thought it was working until I just put four of one number in and it still accepted it. I tried adding an if statement however now it doesn't count any of the correct digits that have been but in.

```
import random

number = random.choice(range(1000, 9999))
number = str(number)
print(number)

flag = True
while flag:
    cow = 0
    bull = 0
    user = input('Number ')
    user = str(user)
    for item in user:
        x = number.count(item)
        y = int(item)
        if y <= x:
            bull += 1
        else:
            cow += 1


    print(f"You have {bull} bulls, and {cow} cows!")
    if bull == 4:
        print(f'The computers number is {number}')
        flag = False
    else:
        print("Guess again")
```

I have been trying all sorts of different ways to try and fix my problem and I just can't work it out :(

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "I just put four of one number in and it still accepted it"? Give the specific test case and output.

Comment: To help me understand, say the number is "1 1 3 4" and the user puts in '2 1 1 1', what should the program output?

Comment: I can't see how it is relevant to compare the item integer value to the number of occurences of the item in the number? You probably want to check if each digit is contained in the number.

Comment: When the user's digit matches a digit in the number, remove it from the number so you can't count it again.

Comment: Why do you do `user = str(user)`? It's already a string.

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of `number`. Then when the user guesses a digit right, remove it from this copy. This way, if they guess the digit more times than it appears in the number, the extra guesses won't be copied.

This copy should be a list so you can use its `remove()` method.

```
while True:
    cow = 0
    bull = 0
    user = input('Number ')
    num_list = list(number)
    for item in user:
        if item in num_list:
            bull += 1
            num_list.remove(item)
        else:
            cow += 1

    print(f"You have {bull} bulls, and {cow} cows!")
    if bull == 4:
        print(f'The computer's number is {number}')
        break
    else:
        print("Guess again")
```

Comment: That works perfectly, earlier I had tried a similar concept but ultimately failed! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Made a couple of changes, based on previous suggestions and my own personal thoughts.  A little bit of error checking to ensure the person entered a number, and recording the persons guesses so guessing the same number multiple times won't count against them.

```
import random

orig_number = random.choice(range(1000, 9999))
copy_number = str(orig_number)
cows = 0
bulls = 0
guesses = []

def convert_to_int(data):
    if data is None:
        return False

    try:
        id = int(data)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

while True:
    guess = input("Guess a number > ")
    if not convert_to_int(str(guess)[0]):
        print("That was not a number")
        continue

    if str(guess)[0] in guesses:
        print("You already guessed that number")
        continue
    elif str(guess)[0] in copy_number:
        print("Good guess, you get a bull")
        bulls += 1
        copy_number = copy_number.replace(str(guess)[0],'')
    else:
        print("Too bad, you get a cow")
        cows += 1

    guesses.append(str(guess)[0])

    print("You have {} cows and {} bulls".format(cows,bulls))
    if len(copy_number) == 0: break
    
print("Congratulations!  You guessed all the numbers.  The original number was {}".format(orig_number))
```

From a test run:

```
Guess a number > a
That was not a number
Guess a number > -   
That was not a number
Guess a number > 9   
Too bad, you get a cow     
You have 1 cows and 0 bulls
Guess a number > 1
Too bad, you get a cow     
You have 2 cows and 0 bulls
Guess a number > 4
Too bad, you get a cow     
You have 3 cows and 0 bulls
Guess a number > 3
Too bad, you get a cow     
You have 4 cows and 0 bulls
Guess a number > 6
Too bad, you get a cow
You have 5 cows and 0 bulls
Guess a number > 5
Good guess, you get a bull
You have 5 cows and 1 bulls
Guess a number > 7
Too bad, you get a cow
You have 6 cows and 1 bulls
Guess a number > 8
Too bad, you get a cow
You have 7 cows and 1 bulls
Guess a number > 9
You already guessed that number
Guess a number > 0
Good guess, you get a bull
You have 7 cows and 2 bulls
Guess a number > 1
You already guessed that number
Guess a number > 2
Good guess, you get a bull
You have 7 cows and 3 bulls
Congratulations!  You guessed all the numbers.  The original number was 2055
```